# Add a watermark to image before uploading? AS3 + Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, image-processing, upload, watermark

For the past few hours I've been trying to figure out a way to add a watermark to an image file before uploading it using the `FileReference.upload();` method. The uploading works already. I just have to figure out how to get a small watermark (PNG image with alpha-transparency) on the lower right of the image file. Another thing is, I **don't** want to modify the source file. I just want to add the watermark on upload.

What approach would you recommend for this type of setup? I also can't seem to find any pre-made classes already that I can use for this certain thing. Is this not a very common task? And **no** I can't use server-side (PHP) to do the watermarking because I'm communicating directly to a service's API, not through my server.

Comment: The problem is that you'd have to load the image into the Flash Players memory, then do some operation like in the answers below, then send it to the server. The normal file upload streams your file to the server so that only a few bytes at a time are loaded into memory. This may work for small files, but with bigger images you'll get into trouble. Is this a trade-off you can handle?

Comment: I'm still considering my options. If it proves to be too much for a load on the app, I might have to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set watermark(alpha image) as higher child index than ur uploading image in a group or box and you can save these container as bitmap or jpeg image.

```
   <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="0x3322ff" id="comp">
        <s:Image source="{upload-image-source}" width="100%" height="100%"/> 
        <s:Image source="{water-mark-image-source(alpha png file)}" width="100%" height="100%"/> 
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

you can save this container as image.

```
        var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(comp.width,comp.height);
        bmpd.draw(comp);

        var jpgenc:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(80);
        var imgByteArray:ByteArray = jpgenc.encode(bmpd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically just add the image and the watermark to a BitmapData and then use a PNG encoder such as http://www.kaourantin.net/2005/10/png-encoder-in-as3.html to create a PNG out of the resulting image. Then you can upload to your server and the original image will still be unaltered.